# Android client connecting to python webservice that uses SOAPpy

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, soapui

I am new to SOAP programming and is looking for ways for my android app to be able to communicate with a python webservice written in SOAPpy. I found on the internet that communicating using socket might be one of the choices but other that that, can i use HTTP/HTTPS to do so? WifiPositioningSoapAPI() contain functions that allows me to manipulate the XML files where the data are stored.

```
class StartSOAPServer:
    def __init__(self):
    api = WifiPositionSoapAPI()
    handler = SOAPpy.SOAPServer(("", Config.SOAP_PORT))
    handler.registerObject(api, Config.NAMESPACE)
    print "SOAP server running at IP Address %s port %s."  %  (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname() ), Config.SOAP_PORT)
    handler.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and getPassword() is on one of the .py that i interact with on the python server (just a folder that have lots of .py files)

```
public class WifiPositioningServices {
private final String NAMESPACE = "urn:WifiPositioningSystem";
//private final String METHOD_NAME = "GetPassword";
//private final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:WifiPositioningSystem/GetPassword";
private final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080";
private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;

public WifiPositioningServices(){

}

public String[] getPassword(String loginID){

    String[] temp = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "GetPassword");

    PropertyInfo quotesProperty = new PropertyInfo();
    quotesProperty.setName("LoginID");
    quotesProperty.setValue(loginID);
    quotesProperty.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(quotesProperty);

    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    String result = "";
    HttpTransportSE httpRequest = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try
    {
        httpRequest.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        result =  response.toString();
        temp = result.split(";");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return temp;
}
}
```